# Kera's Functional API performs better than Sequential

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

As far as I know, Kera's Functional API only provides more flexibility than Sequential.
However, when I was trying to build a simple neural network by Functional API and Sequential for multi-class classification, the accuracy of the models were completely different and Functional API yielded a far better result than Sequential.

This is the model build by Sequential:

```
model_1 = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Input(shape=(10,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax")
])
metrics = [
    keras.metrics.Accuracy(name="accuracy"),
]
model_1.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=metrics)
history_1 = model_1.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
```

The 100th epoch's result from Sequential:

```
loss: 0.1522 - accuracy: 9.2593e-05 - val_loss: 0.2496 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

However, when I built the model by Functional API:

```
model_1 = keras.Sequential()
model_1.add(layers.Input(shape=(10, )))
model_1.add(layers.Dense(100, "relu"))
model_1.add(layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax"))
model_1.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics="accuracy")
history_1 = model_1.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
```

The 100th epoch's result was brilliant:

```
loss: 0.1518 - accuracy: 0.9540 - val_loss: 0.2497 - val_accuracy: 0.9172
```

So the question is - I suppose both API should perform the same and I shall have implemented both model more or less the same, so I wonder why the performance was so significantly different. Or if I had made any mistakes during my model construction?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: There is a difference, you are not passing the same accuracy metric to both models, just compare with metrics=["accuracy"] on both.

Comment: It should not make any difference both the type of initialization are valid, and should give the same performance, You can check your data and Weight initialization for disparity

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Yes, if I pass ```metrics=["accuracy"]``` to both models, they both perform well. But may I further ask the subtle difference between them?